# sed or awk to move one chunk of text betwen first pattern pair into second pair?

Tags: sed, awk

I need to process a text file. Need to move the chunk of text between the first pattern pair into the second pattern pair (above whatever was already there between the second pattern pair.

Sample input:

```
...many lines of text
[pattern]
chunk of text
text I need to move
[/pattern]
...more lines of text
[pattern]
something here or empty
[/pattern]
...more lines of text
```

Indended output:

```
...many lines of text
[pattern]
[/pattern]
...more lines of text
[pattern]
chunk of text
text I need to move
something here or empty
[/pattern]
...more lines of text
```

Is there any sed or awk command that can do that? I searched all over the Net and could not get it working. Thank you!

Comment: Are there more than two such blocks? If so, how do you distinguish which one to move from and which to move to? This could be done in `sed`, but it would be pretty hairy. In AWK, it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/\[pattern\]/ {
    flag = 1
    count++
    print
    next
}

flag == 1 && count == 2 {
    print accum
    accum = ""
    flag = 0
}

/\[\/pattern\]/ {flag = 0}

flag == 0 {print}
flag == 1 && count == 1 {
    accum = accum delim $0
    delim = RS
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, but it doesn't work when there is nothing between the 2nd pattern pair. like this:`...many lines of text
[pattern]
chunk of text
text I need to move
[/pattern]
...more lines of text
[pattern]
something here or empty
[/pattern]
...more lines of text
`

Comment: my previous reply did not come out right. When there is nothing between the second pattern pair, the script does not seem to work. Sorry to bug you, but I don't know awk well enough to figure out the answer quickly.

Comment: @May: I just needed to change the order of some of the statements to fix that problem. Please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

data=File.open("file").read
puts data.gsub(/(.[^\]]*\[pattern\])(.[^\[]*)(\[\/pattern\])(.[^\]]*\[pattern\])(.*)\z/m , "\\1\n\\3\\4\\2\\5" )
```

test run

```
$ cat file    
1 2 3
[pattern]
chunk of text
text I need to move
[/pattern]
4 5 6
[pattern]
something here or empty
[/pattern]
7 8 9    
[pattern]
blah blah
[/pattern]

$ ruby script.rb    
1 2 3
[pattern]
[/pattern]
4 5 6
[pattern]
chunk of text
text I need to move

something here or empty
[/pattern]
7 8 9    
[pattern]
blah blah
[/pattern]
```