# Moving chunks of data in a file with awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm moving my bookmarks from kippt.com to pinboard.in.

I exported my bookmarks from Kippt and for some reason, they were storing tags (preceded by #) and description within the same field. Pinboard keeps tags and description separated.

This is what a Kippt bookmark looks like after export:

```
<DT><A HREF="http://www.example.org/" ADD_DATE="1412337977" LIST="Bookmarks">This is a title</A>
<DD>#tag1 #tag2 This is a description
```

This is what it should look like before importing into Pinboard:

```
<DT><A HREF="http://www.example.org/" ADD_DATE="1412337977" LIST="Bookmarks" TAGS="tag1,tag2">This is a title</A>
<DD>This is a description
```

So basically, I need to replace `#tag1 #tag2` by `TAGS="tag1,tag2"` and move it on the first line within `<A>`.

I've been reading about moving chunks of data here: [sed or awk to move one chunk of text betwen first pattern pair into second pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347508/sed-or-awk-to-move-one-chunk-of-text-betwen-first-pattern-pair-into-second-pair)

I haven't been to come up with a good recipe so far. Any insight?

Edit:

Here's an actual example of what the input file looks like (3 entries out of 3500):

```
<DT><A HREF="http://phabricator.org/" ADD_DATE="1412973315" LIST="Bookmarks">Phabricator</A>
<DD>#bug #tracking 

<DT><A HREF="http://qz.com/261426/the-hidden-commands-for-diagnosing-and-improving-your-netflix-streaming-quality/" ADD_DATE="1412838293" LIST="Inbox">The hidden commands for diagnosing and improving your Netflix streaming quality – Quartz</A>

<DT><A HREF="http://www.farmholidays.is/" ADD_DATE="1412337977" LIST="Bookmarks">Icelandic Farm Holidays | Local experts in Iceland vacations</A>
<DD>#iceland #tour #car #drive #self Self-driving tour of Iceland
```

Comment: Does it have to be used with `awk`/`sed` or is e.g. `python` possible as well?

Comment: It could be Python, which I'm starting to learn. It could be another language as well (Ruby, etc.) but I'd like to learn on a language I already know :-) Thanks.

Comment: What is supposed to happen to `<DD>#bug #tracking` in your example? Shall the line be deleted completely or shall it result in `<DD>`?

Comment: `<DD>#iceland #tour #car #drive #self Self-driving tour of Iceland` should become `<DD>Self-driving tour of Iceland`

Comment: Yes, sure, I got that. But the second line only contains tags and no further description. So my question is whether the result shall have a line that only contains `<DD>` or whether that line should be deleted?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, in the first entry, DD can be removed or stay, both would get parsed correctly by Pinboard.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most beautiful solution, but since it seems to be a one-time-thing it should be sufficient.

```
import re
dt = re.compile('^<DT>')
dd = re.compile('^<DD>')


with open('bookmarks.xml', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(dt, line):
            current_dt = line.strip()
        elif re.match(dd, line):
            current_dd = line
            tags = [w for w in line[4:].split(' ') if w.startswith('#')]
            current_dt = re.sub('(<A[^>]+)>', '\\1 TAGS="' + ','.join([t[1:] for t in tags]) + '">', current_dt)
            for t in tags:
                current_dd = current_dd.replace(t + ' ', '')
            if current_dd.strip() == '<DD>':
                current_dd = ""
        else:
            print current_dt
            print current_dd
            current_dt = ""
            current_dd = ""

    print current_dt
    print current_dd
```

If some parts of the code are not clear, just tell me. You can of course use python to write the lines to a file instead of printing them, or even modify the original file.

Edit: Added if-clause so that empty `<DD>` lines won't show up in the result.

Comment: Thanks Tim! It didn't work out of the box, because there were some corner cases in my file (like description coming before tags, DD missing) but after some sed manipulations, I managed to get a proper file to treat with the Python script with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

script.awk

```
BEGIN{FS="#"}

/^<DT>/{
    if(d==1) print "<DT>"s # for printing lines with no tags 
    s=substr($0,5);tags="" # Copying the line after "<DT>". You'll know why
    d=1
}

/^<DD>/{
    d=0
    m=match(s,/>/) # Find the end of the HREF descritor first match of ">"
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sub(/ $/,"",$i);tags=tags","$i} # Concatenate tags
    td=match(tags,/ /) # Parse for tag description (marked by a preceding space).
    if(td==0){ # No description exists
        tags=substr(tags,2)
        tagdes=""
    }
    else{ # Description exists
        tagdes=substr(tags,td)
        tags=substr(tags,2,td-2)
    }
    print "<DT>" substr(s,1,m-1) ", TAGS=\"" tags "\"" substr(s,m)
    print "<DD>" tagdes
}
```

---

```
awk -f script.awk kippt > pinboard
```

---

INPUT

```
<DT><A HREF="http://phabricator.org/" ADD_DATE="1412973315" LIST="Bookmarks">Phabricator</A>
<DD>#bug #tracking 

<DT><A HREF="http://qz.com/261426/the-hidden-commands-for-diagnosing-and-improving-your-netflix-streaming-quality/" ADD_DATE="1412838293" LIST="Inbox">The hidden commands for diagnosing and improving your Netflix streaming quality – Quartz</A>

<DT><A HREF="http://www.farmholidays.is/" ADD_DATE="1412337977" LIST="Bookmarks">Icelandic Farm Holidays | Local experts in Iceland vacations</A>
<DD>#iceland #tour #car #drive #self Self-driving tour of Iceland
```

OUTPUT:

```
<DT><A HREF="http://phabricator.org/" ADD_DATE="1412973315" LIST="Bookmarks", TAGS="bug,tracking">Phabricator</A>
<DD>
<DT><A HREF="http://qz.com/261426/the-hidden-commands-for-diagnosing-and-improving-your-netflix-streaming-quality/" ADD_DATE="1412838293" LIST="Inbox">The hidden commands for diagnosing and improving your Netflix streaming quality – Quartz</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.farmholidays.is/" ADD_DATE="1412337977" LIST="Bookmarks", TAGS="iceland,tour,car,drive,self">Icelandic Farm Holidays | Local experts in Iceland vacations</A>
<DD> Self-driving tour of Iceland
```